# Importing Bootstrap js files inside HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

## Question

How can I import Bootstrap from my node_modules/ into a js file without using node/express?

## Introduction

I have installed Bootstrap5 in my Yarn monorepo because I don't wanna use CDNs, and I think is more flexible to configure with SASS if I have all the bootstrap package inside node_modules/.

> yarn add bootstrap @popperjs/core

After compiling the Bootstrap scss and merging it with my custom stylesheets, I have created the following html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Company</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img
            src="../assets/images/logo/logo-transparent.png"
            alt="Company"
            width="40"
            height="40"
          />
        </a>

        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Careers</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

## How can I include the Bootstrap JS modules without using CDNs?

In the official docs of Bootstrap, it says that we can import all the JavaScript stuff with:

```
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

But... as I have added Bootstrap to my project via Yarn (just for customizing the styles), I have thought to create my own script.js file to import everything from `node_modules`:

- index.html:

`<script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>`

- js/main.js

```js
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"; // Just import everything from bootstrap
```

But I am getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "bootstrap". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Also, inside index.html, if I do:

```
<script src="../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

it works OK, but I don't like the `../../../node_modules/`. How can I handle this?

--Note: I am not using node/express in my project, just HTML, JavaScript and SCSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might download the bootstrap file from the CDN server and serve it with the rest of your project. That way you aren't relying on a CDN or node/node modules.

Comment: Hey, can you explain me why is better to download the files instead of using a package manager for a HTML5 project?

Comment: It's just a bit simpler. If you are already using node/yarn then there's not a huge difference, but if you are only using yarn for this then it makes your project a lot simpler. It also simplifies serving the project. Generally, you don't want to serve node_modules publicly, so importing from node_modules in a properly hardened environment would be impossible.

Comment: Downloading the source code is a good idea too, but I think using a package manager is better for monorepos. I have decided to use parcel to build a distributed version of the project, in order to exclude the node_modules. Also, in dev mode, I am able to import js correctly. Thx very much.